# Huge string into a WinForm RichTextBox

Tags: c#, .net, string, winforms, richtextbox

I have a big string (20K lines * 100 character each).

I need to place this string into a RichTextBox (or any similar thing) of a windows forms application, currently it takes 40 second to do so, (appending the String itself takes 40 sec).

Here is a code snippet

```
StringBuilder sb = Very_big_String_Builder_Object;
string appendMe = sb.ToString();
uniqueOutput.SelectionStart = uniqueOutput.TextLength;
uniqueOutput.SelectedText = appendMe;
```

I also tried

```
StringBuilder sb = Very_big_String_Builder_Object;
string appendMe = sb.ToString();
uniqueOutput.Text = appendMe;
```

which was a little bit worst.

Is there anything within .NET (up to 4.5) that can help ?

Comment: Why do you need to display that much information all in one go? Nobody could realistically read all of that.

Comment: Do you want to read a book where each page has 20000 lines? Of course not. Why do you expect it from your users? Show only the relevant part, either with paging or filtered.

Comment: well, even it looks weird but the user will take it into another few programs and files, which are usually changing process. I can output into a file but it'll take more time for them to save to file, locate file, open file and then copy and paste. also there is more than single output RichTextBox

Comment: Maybe [`LoadFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f99sst7(v=vs.110).aspx) is faster?

Comment: Are you saying they're going to copy and paste 20K lines of text into other programs/documents? I've not tried it but I'm sure the RichTextBox won't be happy when you try and highlight that much text.

Comment: @Equalsk it takes less than a second to copy/paste this from a RichTextBox (from the UI), which made me wondering if there is a way to do it the same speed

Comment: Creating a StringBuilder through a loop 20k times appending a `new string('X', 100);` is instant for me.  Placing that StringBuilder into a RichTextBox takes less than a second.  Something else is happening with your code.

Comment: Why do you use a RTB? Unless you actually want to format portions of that string a simple TextBox should be a good deal faster. also why insert it instead of pre-building the string and then replacing the whole Text property?

Comment: @MickyD  I make some processing internally before display, but this is a good point

Comment: @TaW This is what I did finally, but needed to implement a listener to handle CTRL+A and few other things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a TextBox with multiline True:

```
txtMulti.text = Very_big_String_Builder_Object.ToString;
```

Comment: The most valid solution, it reduced the time to less than 2 seconds, but I needed to make a listener to handle CTRL+A click

Comment: Hotkeys are often a problem - check for other controls/containers that may be capturing the Ctrl-A. Menus "with standard items" often suck up control keys.

Answer (score 2):

Disabling WordWrap and DetectUrls will surely save you a couple of seconds.

Comment: This reduced the time from 40 second into 30~35 seconds, nice recommendation